# SceneKit – Converting Objective-C block to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, scenekit

Is there a Swift guru that would know how to convert this code in Objective-c to Swift?

```
SCNAnimationEventBlock chainEventBlock = ^(CAAnimation *animation, id animatedObject, BOOL playingBackward) {
        [self.mainSkeleton addAnimation:secondAnim forKey:secondKey];
};

if (firstAnim.animationEvents == nil || firstAnim.animationEvents.count == 0) {
    firstAnim.animationEvents = @[[SCNAnimationEvent animationEventWithKeyTime:fadeTime block:chainEventBlock]];
} else {
    NSMutableArray *pastEvents = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:firstAnim.animationEvents];
    [pastEvents addObject:[SCNAnimationEvent animationEventWithKeyTime:fadeTime block:chainEventBlock]];
    firstAnim.animationEvents = pastEvents;
}
```

In Swift, I tried :

```
var chainEventBlock : ((CAAnimation , AnyObject , Bool) -> (SCNAnimationEventBlock))?
chainEventBlock = { (animation, animatedObject, playingBackward)->(SCNAnimationEventBlock) in
    return self.mainSkeleton?.addAnimation(anim2, forKey: secondKey)
}

if anim1?.animationEvents == nil || anim1?.animationEvents.count == 0 {
    anim1?.animationEvents = [SCNAnimationEvent(keyTime: fadeTime, block: chainEventBlock)]
}
```

The error is:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared the return type of the block as `SCNAnimationEventBlock` but you don't return that.

Either return an object of that type (not an optional!), or return nothing and change the declaration of `chainEventBlock`.

```
let chainEventBlock: SCNAnimationEventBlock = { animation, animatedObject, playingBackwards in
    self.mainSkeleton?.addAnimation(anim2, forKey: secondKey)
    return
}

if anim1?.animationEvents == nil || anim1?.animationEvents.count == 0 {
    anim1?.animationEvents = [SCNAnimationEvent(keyTime: fadeTime, block: chainEventBlock)]
}
```